# VMware lock prevention error

Tags: vmware-esxi, truenas, mikrotik

I have a TrueNas connected via a 10Gbit interface to a CRS326-24S+2Q+ running switchOS. I also have a 10Gbit interface connected to VMware connected to the same switch. They are both on the same VLAN for ISCSI storage. I keep getting the following messages every so often and the VM freezes. I am seeing significant TX pauses on the error tab (not sure if this is the issue or not). I also unchecked the flow control tab from the link to see if it would fix the issue and it hasn't. This is not on an HA setup.  Just one host connected to TrueNas.  Any suggestions?

> The lock protecting Apache_Debian.vmdk has been lost, possibly due to
> underlying storage issues. If this virtual machine is configured to be
> highly available, ensure that the virtual machine is running on some
> other host before clicking OK.

Comment: Pause frames don't indicate any problem, there normal for iSCSI - flow control needs to be activated on all devices though (NAS, switch, host)! You should diagnose the NAS OS & hardware for any issues. Both the Mikrotik switch and the NAS hardware might not be very well suited for the tasks.

Comment: If there isn't anything else, I'd try connecting host and NAS directly first.